# Blender 2.8 (Shading/Textured Solid)

Tags: texturing

[image]

Hello,

Dropping into 2.8 as noted in another thread and trying to get to grips with the new interface. There is one thing I am having hard finding, or finding the equivalent of and that is the "Textured Solid" option.

I would really appreciate the help :)

Comment: You'll find some answers here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydgpVmsQAIM
(to switch to the shaders view, click the 'shading' tab on the upper part of the screen/window)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Blender Render has been completely removed in Blender 2.8, so this functionality is no longer available.

Could't agree more about having to use materials slowing down my workflow when I'm going to be exporting to something that completely ignores the materials anyway.

However there are at least ways of speeding the process up, and you can still get the same visual feel as Textured Solid.

The button to the right of the colour option lets you quickly pick a new input node type while avoiding the node editor. So you can quickly switch to an image like this:

[image: Quick shader image setup]

Then just select the image with the dropdown that appears.

You can get a similar visual feel as "Textured Solid" in the viewport by setting your shading up like this:

[image: Textured Solid visual feel]

(I have both of these set up this way in my startup file. Then when I need to add a new texture, I just duplicate the material and change the texture.)

Answer (score 1):

Not there is not. It's a Blender Internal thing and was already gone with Cycles. Set the viewport's shading to lookdev and it will do:

[image]

Comment: The problem then becomes speed and accessibility. 

Whereas before in 2.7
- Unwrap model 
- Load texture in UV editor
- Model now shows the material. 

2.8 
- Unwrap model 
- Make a material
- Set up nodes to use bitmap texture
- Apply material to the model
- Make a material and nodes for each and every model. 

Now, this is fine if you work is to  be rendered in Blender, but I work in a game engine and want to spend as little time as possible within Blender's material system. Not to mention I now have to deal with another panel entirely in my workspace, the node system