# Texture not showing in Rig

Tags: texturing

After the update of blender 2.8. A minecraft rig(Black Plasma's rig v2), I've been using not showing any texture(skin) on viewport and in rendered mode the texture(skin) is same on front and back of the rig. The minecraft rig works in Blender 2.79. It uses cycles.
[image: In viewport][image: In rendered mode. First is front view and second is back view]

Comment: I just did this and it worked for me, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124225/blender-2-8-shading-textured-solid

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is usually because Material is not selected under Viewport Shading.

[image: Viewport Shading]

But there may be other causes such as lighting, CPU/GPU usage, and other things.

*edit: This qualifies for blender 2.8 and 2.79